# css what is the "at" property?

Tags: css, phpstorm

I found a css file on internet that starts with

```
@sR: #418a95;
@sRLight: #418a95 + #222;
@sRDark: #418a95 - #222;
@darkGrey:#6b6b6b;
@offWhite:#f6f3f7;
@bg:#f6f3f7 - #111;
@darkBg:#f6f3f7 - #222;
```

and then in code, they do this:

```
background:@sR;
```

Though my IDE, which is phpStorm, tells me that this is not a correct css style.

what is that please?

#### Edit

this is the website 
http://codepen.io/alimudassar111/pen/idyIq

Comment: Pretty sure that's using a pre-processed CSS engine, not natively CSS3.

Comment: Looks like it would be http://lesscss.org/ or something similar.

Comment: @addy2012 that is different than above

Comment: To answer the question, in preprocessing languages you can use `@` to define a variable so that when the CSS is processsed, you don't have to write the value of a certain CSS Style (such as a color for the main theme of a website) all over the place

Comment: @epascarello I added the website to the updated question, please could you tell me how to know the pure css for that code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Less](http://lesscss.org/), a CSS preprocessor, and the at sign marks a variable.

Comment: I updated my question with the website, could you tell me how to get the pure css for that code please?

Comment: You can't set variables with pure CSS.

Comment: I am not asking about variables, but I am asking about the pure css in that website that let the style of the table, got me please?

Comment: `background: #418a95;`